# How can I access a solidity mapping address => struct using Ether.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

I'm having some trouble calling a function accessing a mapping in ethers.js. Here is the mapping:

```
mapping(address => Player) public playerInfo;
```

Here is the struct it returns:

```
struct Player {
    string name; // Allows players to more easily identify eachother
    uint gameId; // gameId generated from gameNumber
    uint buyinAmount; // How much a player has bought in with
    uint withdrawalAmount; // How much a player has requested a withdrawal for
    bool withdrawalReq; // Tracks if a player has submitted a request
    bool verifyReqs; // TO verify that all withdrawal requests look good at table
    bool hasWithdrawn; // To signify that a player has paidout to prevent triggering of any functions after they receieve back their funds
    bool isInGame; // Is in game bool
    bool isHost; // Is host
}
```

For simplicity, I want to get the player information from the function called getOtherPlayerInfo:

```
function getOtherPlayerInfo(address addr) public view returns (Player memory) {
        return playerInfo[address];
    }
```

To access in the front end, I just define a value otherPlayerInfo that returns an array so I can access with indexes. Here that is:

```
    const otherPlayerInfo = useContractReader(writeContracts, "YourContract", "getOtherPlayerInfo", "0x59D101AD9DdeA84C0e11DA137000Dd91A0b20c79");
```

The problem here is that for whatever reason, otherPlayerInfo is undefined when trying to print it to the console. I assume there must be an issue with parsing the string, but I do not know. I tried to utilize the documentation (using .toString, getAddress, getIcapAddress, etc), but its methods did not seem to help.

I know that the setter and getters work, because when I hardcode the solidity function with msg.sender like so it works:

```
function getPlayerInfo() public view returns (Player memory) {
    return playerInfo[msg.sender];
}
```

(Here is the React code that works with that):

```
    const otherPlayerInfo = useContractReader(writeContracts, "YourContract", "getOtherPlayerInfo");
```

As expected, the above code returns the playerInfo without issues. However, I do not want just to be able to get msg.sender data - I want to be able to pass in any address to get that info.

Comment: Can you check your `getOtherPlayerInfo` function parameter? `return playerInfo[address];` should be `return playerInfo[addr];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it may be a problem with the syntax:

```
function getOtherPlayerInfo(address addr) public view returns (Player memory) 
    {
        return playerInfo[address];
    }
```

Here, `address` refers to the type address and not to the parameter `addr`, which is what you are looking for. Nonetheless, I would be very surprised if you were able to compile the contract as such.

Then, by setting the mapping as a public state variable `playerInfo` like this:

```
mapping(address => Player) public playerInfo;
```

You are implicitly creating a getter function that behaves exactly as `getOtherPlayerInfo`:

```
function playerInfo(address addr) public view returns (Player memory) 
    {
        return playerInfo[addr];
    }
```

As stated in the [Solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/contracts.html#state-variable-visibility). Therefore, your function is not necessary.

Then, if you have a contract as follows:

```
struct Player {
    string name;
    uint gameId;
}

contract Players {
    mapping(address => Player) public playerInfo;

    function setUpPlayerInfo(address addr, Player memory player) public {
        playerInfo[addr] = player;
    }
}
```

It will work as expected if you compile it and, then, test it:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Players", function () {
  it("Sets up and returns player info via public state variable", async function () {
    const Players = await ethers.getContractFactory("Players");
    const players = await Players.deploy();
    await players.deployed();
    
    const [signer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const playerInfo = {
      name: "Test name",
      gameId: 1,
    }

    await players.setUpPlayerInfo(signer.address, playerInfo);

    const playerInfoResponse = await players.playerInfo(signer.address)

    expect(playerInfoResponse[0]).to.equal(playerInfo.name);
    expect(playerInfoResponse[1]).to.equal(playerInfo.gameId);
  });
});
```

I have made both files, [contract](https://remix.ethereum.org/#gist=88fff1d420b7ac14cc2d0d7e1e7a3886) and [tests](https://remix.ethereum.org/#gist=cc539daeef32980c605b563fcece18a1), available on Remix.